# Decoration with raise option on a cycle path engenders bad result

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations

I am currently trying to do some decoration on a path built from a list of coordinates and cycle. I observe a weird result at the closing point of the cycle. I am looking for a solution to remove it.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,decorations}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\coordinate (K) at (3,1);
\coordinate (of) at (7,1.5);
%\draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (10,5);
\draw[decorate,black,decoration={curveto,raise=-10pt}] (K) plot [smooth cycle,tension=0.7] coordinates {(3,1) (5,1.2) (7,1) (8,3) (7,4.5) (5,4.5) (2,4) (1.7,2.5)};
\draw[black] (K) plot [smooth cycle,tension=0.7] coordinates {(3,1) (5,1.2) (7,1) (8,3) (7,4.5) (5,4.5) (2,4) (1.7,2.5)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Bad paths]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=9,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter

\pgfdeclaredecoration{raise close}{start}{
    \state{start}[width=+0pt,next state=iterate,persistent precomputation=\pgfdecoratepathhascornerstrue]
        {\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}}
    \state{iterate}[width=+\pgfdecorationsegmentlength]{\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}}
    \state{final}{\pgfpathclose}
}
\pgfdeclaredecoration{raise open}{start}{
    \state{start}[width=+0pt,next state=iterate,persistent precomputation=\pgfdecoratepathhascornerstrue]
        {\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}}
    \state{iterate}[width=+\pgfdecorationsegmentlength]{\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}}
    \state{final}{}
}
\tikz{
    \draw[decorate,decoration={raise close,amplitude=-10pt,segment length=1pt}]
          plot[smooth cycle,tension=.7]coordinates{(3,1)(5,1.2)(7,1)(8,3)(7,4.5)(5,4.5)(2,4)(1.7,2.5)};
    \draw plot[smooth cycle,tension=.7]coordinates{(3,1)(5,1.2)(7,1)(8,3)(7,4.5)(5,4.5)(2,4)(1.7,2.5)};
}

\tikz{
    \draw[double,double distance=10pt]
          plot[smooth cycle,tension=.7]coordinates{(3,1)(5,1.2)(7,1)(8,3)(7,4.5)(5,4.5)(2,4)(1.7,2.5)};
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

<del>Perhaps add these lines before your picture.

    \makeatletter
    \pgfutil@namedef{pgf@decorate@@curveto@initial}{safeinit}
    \pgfutil@namedef{pgf@decorate@@curveto@safeinit@options}{next state=initial,width=1pt}
    \pgfutil@namedef{pgf@decorate@@curveto@safeinit@code}{\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}}
    \pgfutil@namedef{pgf@decorate@@curveto@final@code}{\pgfpathclose}
    \makeatother</del>

Comment: Thank you. It works in my case but it seems to not work in all cases (it damages other kind of decoration not presented here).

Comment: @Guuk Sorry I was not aware of how general this question could be. In general you can look at `pgfmoduledecorations.code.tex` line 2138-2144. It tells you how `curveto` is defined. And you can make your own definition.

Comment: Yes I know. I just put this comment to precise some limits of your first proposition. Thank you for the second one.